# Excel - Count based on criteria in 3 other columns

Tags: excel, count, pivot-table

I'm looking for help in getting a count based on criteria in 3 other columns. I started to do a pivot table, but I cannot see how to add an IF statement to the distinct count there.

I need a count of each customer within the customer type, by each supplier, if the Cases > 0 for that year.

Here's a sample data set:

| Supplier | Customer | Type | 2019 Cases | 2020 Cases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Al's Store | Package | 3 | 2 |
| ABC | Ben's | Package | 0 | 6 |
| ABC | Kroger | Grocery | 2 | 1 |
| ABC | Publix | Grocery | 1 | 0 |
| XYZ | Al's Store | Package | 0 | 5 |
| XYZ | Ben's | Package | 4 | 0 |
| XYZ | Kroger | Grocery | 0 | 1 |
| XYZ | Publix | Grocery | 3 | 7 |

I need a result like this.  My actual report will have each supplier on their own tab.

| Supplier | Type | 2019 Customer Count | 2020 Customer Count | My Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Package | 1 | 2 | Al's bought in both years, but Ben's only in 2020 |
| ABC | Grocery | 2 | 1 | Kroger bought in both years, but Publix only in 2019 |
| XYZ | Package | 1 | 1 | Al only bought in 2020, Ben only bought in 2019 |
| XYZ | Grocery | 1 | 2 | Kroger only bought in 2020 |

Thanks!

Comment: a pivot table or COUNTIFS will do this, what have you tried?

Comment: In the pivot table I tried, I only see the Count option, which gives me 2 for everything, because it includes the 0 cases.

Comment: Look at COUNTIFS as Scott suggest. [link to COUNTIFS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)